# Add API to Polymer web component

Tags: polymer, web-component

I am building a Polymer web component that should respond to mouse/touch events. I would like to bind the `on-tap="{{$.myElement.show}}"` where `show` is a function in the element:

```
show: function(e) {
  // Do something with the event here
}
```

Is there anyway to define a public API in Polymer. The route I am going at the moment is to have `attributes="event"` on the element then the parent element has `on-tap="{{updateEvent}}"`:

```
updateEvent: function(e) {
  this.$.myElement.event = e;
}
```

The element then just has:

```
eventChanged: function() {
  show(this.event);
}
```

Which just seems boilerplaty (think that is a made up word). Can I add the `show` function to the element prototype somehow?

Comment: Am I being stupid here, can you even access the API from the DOM? Do you need to provide `constructor="MyElement"` so that you can create it in JavaScript `var el = new MyElement` then be able to do `el.show`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `show()` is a method on your element, just use `on-tap="{{show}}"`. `show()` is part of the element's public APi.

But it looks like you want is to call another element's method? This came up recently in a pull request: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-dev/pull/30

What you have with setting `this.$.myElement.event = e;` and using `eventChanged()` in `myElement` works. You can also just call the element's method directly:

```
updateEvent: function(e) {
  this.$.myElement.show();
}
```

Here are a few other ways: http://jsbin.com/guyiritu/1/edit

Comment: That PR is exactly what I'm trying to do! Will track that.